# Python quick sort- recursive error running on terminal

Tags: python, quicksort

would anyone know why I am getting the following recursive error on my **quicksort**? Not sure why I'm getting a "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison". I've asked others and they said that my recursion should not be exceeding:

Here is the code:

```
def merge(array, low, mid, high):

i,j,k = low,mid+1,low
leftarray = array[low:mid+1]
rightarray = array[mid+1:high+1]

temp= [0]*high

while i<=mid and j<=high:

    if array[i]<array[j]:
        temp[k] = array[i]
        i+=1
    else:
        temp[k] = array[j]
        j+=1
    k+=1

if i>mid:
    temp[k:high+1] = array[j:high+1]
else:
    temp[k:high+1] = array[i:mid+1]  

array[low:high+1] = temp[low:high+1]
```

And the error

```
(base) b98-aruba1-guest-10-110-7-206:desktop ericadamian$ python Quicksort1.py
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
(base) b98-aruba1-guest-10-110-7-206:desktop ericadamian$
```

Comment: What is the terminating condition for your recursive function?

Comment: `Quicksort1(array, index, low, index + 1)` This is an infinite recursion. It will call itself with the same `low` and `index` values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53786145/recursionerror-in-python

Comment: Maybe should be `-1` instead of `+1` in the first recursive call - your `high` value is just getting bigger and bigger each time, so the `if` statement will always be `True`

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixes noted in comments.

```
def Quicksort1(array, low, high):               #fix

    if high > low:
        index = Partition(array, low, high)     #fix
        Quicksort1(array, low, index - 1)       #fix
        Quicksort1(array, index + 1, high)      #fix

def Partition(array, low, high):                #fix

    firstitem = array[low]
    j = low
    for i in range(low+1, high+1):              #fix
        if array[i] < firstitem:
            j+=1
            array[j], array[i] = array[i], array[j]
    index = j
    array[low], array[index] = array[index], array[low]     
    return index                                #fix

array = [10, 3, 4, 8, 1, 7]
Quicksort1(array, 0, len(array)-1)              #fix
for j in range(len(array)):                     #fix
    print ("%d" %array[j])                      #fix
```